# start listening @node but do not load data until data added

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using firebase database to store data. I know how to use firebase database.
In my project I've an activity which displays a list of notices from faculties to students and by clicking on list item it will open another activity which is a chat room. In this activity student can ask question related to given notice.

Now, In first list activity I've also added on text view which displays the total number of chat messages for that particular Notice. It works well when i load data from database initially. But i want to change number of chat messages dynamically.
So, i need to listnen at chat_cnt node to update value of message_cnt text view 
and problem is it is a big list so i can not use child_added for each and every notice item and if i use value_event listener than it will load all data unnecessarily at start.

The code is a little bit big so i cannot post it here. But I've described the problem.

Any answer would be appreciated, thanks. Sorry for my english :)

Comment: Can you post the node where this message_cnt is located? In text, not picture

Comment: Hi @RosárioPereiraFernandes sry formy late reply but i've solved my problem by adding one extra node for chat_cnt(You can say a shallow copy). By the way thanks for your response. i'm new to stack overflow so sry again.

Comment: That's ok. I'm glad you soved your problem :)

Comment: Thanks for your effort. :)